# How to position div element right below and left-aligned to another div

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

My setup is this - I'm working on an `ASP.NET MVC 4`. For the user interface and specifically to this question, I'm doing it for the `_Layout` so it is very basic setup that will be shared for all pages. I'm using where I can `bootstrap 3` but the site targets only large display devices so a lot of things will be done with other tools.

However for the basic layout I'm using `bootstrap 3` styled elements but they are customized already so I think this is more general CSS/JS related question than addressing specific framework/lib. Just put it here so I can get the best solution for my problem which is this :

[image: Part of the basic layout]

The different colors are just to make it easier to understand and because I don't have much experience so it will be easier for me to explain what I want to accomplish. I have a `<div id="top-nav-wrapper">` which purpose is only to hold the other 3 divs and to provide the background image, because the layout is centered and fixed to `970px` so on larger resolutions I get this stripe going on on both ends. The style for this wrapper div is pretty simple:

```
#top-nav-wrapper {
    background-image:url('/Content/images/navbar-stripe.png');
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
}
```

Inside the `#top-nav-wrapper` div I have three other div tags. The first is the one with the dark blue background - `<div class="container">`. Here I use `bootstrap 3` class `.container` but it's customized and it's style is :

```
.container {
  max-width: none !important;
  width: 970px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

After this div follows the other with the navigation buttons and the dark yellow background -

```
<div class="container" style="height: 80px; padding-right: 0px
!important; padding-left: 0px !important;">
```

again using the `.container` class with some additional styling which you can see.

The last div is the grey line - `<div class="container" style="background-color: grey; height: 50px;">` and again I use the predefined `.container` class with few changes.

The red-bordered box from the image represents what I want to add now. I need a vertical menu but the design requires that vertical menu to be right under the dark-yellow div. As you can see the `Home` menu link is colored in blue. The left side is the left end of the div too so what I need is nevermind how the window is resized to have the vertical menu always right below the yellow div, aligned to it's bottom-left. To make it more clear I'll post an image of what it should look like :

[image: Left aligned div]

so the first thing that I want and I don't know how to do is to position the div so it's under the menu div and left-aligned with it. The second is that I need the menu to be shown over the grey div, much like it's shown in the image above. Just to make it complete - the idea is for vertical menu to always have the width of the `Home` menu link. But think I got this with a little `jQuery` so my question is entirely about how to position the div the way I want it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the 970px containers start at the left border of the light blue Home link and continue "off screen" to the right. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

In that case, I would set up a single container 970px wide with auto margins to center it, and then placed the other containers inside. If the red box is inside the 970px-wide container, since you know the height of the gray box, you could also just style the red box `margin-top: -50px`

Here's some code, and you can see it in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/robyoder/HbgFE/1/).

### HTML:

```
<div id="top-nav-wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <div style="height: 50px; background: #006"></div>
        <div style="height: 80px; padding-right: 0px
!important; padding-left: 0px !important; background: #eb0;"></div>
        <div style="background-color: grey; height: 50px;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="main-wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <div style="background: red; width: 200px; height: 400px; margin-top: -50px"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS:

```
#top-nav-wrapper {
    background-image:url('/Content/images/navbar-stripe.png');
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    width: 100%;
}

.container {
  max-width: none !important;
  width: 970px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.container div {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you gonna read this since it's weekend but the problem with your code is that actually `#top-nav-wrapper` is no more wrapper since it's inside another div. As you may see `background-repeat:repeat-x;` is because I want this image to be 100% of the width no matter the resolution and all other divs inside the wrapper are centered and with fixed width of `970px` but once I go above `970px` I want my `background-image` stripe to fill the empty space at the top. In other words go to the fiddle example and start stretching the window...

Comment: At some point you will got completely white space on both sides (everything is fixed to 970px after all) but what I need is the background image to fill this space.

Comment: Yes, that's true. I've updated my answer. You can still do the same thing by making sure the red box is inside a `.container`. I gave the background colors only to the fixed-width divs because I don't have the navbar-stripe.png for the nav background.